# Find repository from another project in spring

Tags: java, spring

I have multiple projects using spring 2.1.3 and would like to let them share some entities, together with their repositories.

Sample repository:

```
package com.my.otherproject.pojos;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.ReactiveMongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Repository
public interface UserDataRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<UserData, ObjectId> {
  Mono<UserData> findByEmail(String name);
}
```

The `otherproject` is included with gradle

```
compile project(':pojobase')
```

And I have added

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.my.firstproject", "com.my.otherproject"})
```

to a `@Configuration` file.

When I try to use above Repository in my main project, I get an error saying

> Description:
>
> Parameter 0 of constructor in
>   com.my.firstproject.controllers.CustomerController required a bean of
>   type 'com.my.otherproject.pojos.UserDataRepository' that could not be
>   found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'com.my.otherproject.pojos.UserDataRepository' in your configuration.

Is it somehow possible to use the entities and repositories in my spring app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.my.otherproject.pojos"})` on `Main` class

```
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.my.otherproject.pojos"})
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(Main.class);

   }
}
```

Comment: I'm using `ReactiveMongo`, so JPA doesn't work. But adding `@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.my.otherproject.pojos"})`  accordingly works perfectly. Thanks...